# Link pages to rowCell's in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, row

I have two rowCell's inside a Row widget in my app and I want to assign them different pages. I've tried putting the rowCell's in a GestureDetector, a FlatButton but neither of them have worked (as they should be linked to the Row widget and they need separate links for separate pages.)

Here is the part of my code:

```
  ...
  new Divider(
                height: _height / 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  rowCell(10250, 'MEETUPS'),
                  rowCell(1520, 'FRIENDS'),
                ],
              ),
              new Divider(height: _height / 20, color: Colors.grey),
  ...
```

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: What does "they should be linked to the Row widget and they need separate links for separate pages" mean ?

Comment: @Kahou The two rowCell's are children of the main Row widget. As we can't separate them from the main Row widget, there needs to be a way to use the GestureDetector or the FlatButton solution inside the Row widget with rowCell still being a child.

Comment: Why you can't separate them? What is `rowCell` ? Please show the full code.

Comment: @Kahou A full code isn't necessary. You just have to figure out how to use a GestureDetector for that rowCell which is a subsidiary of the main Row widget. I added a screenshot of the output of the code given to the initial post.

Comment: Because I don't understand your problem, maybe you can see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: if you wrap each RowCell with its own GestureDetector, it should work. You mentioned, it does not work, what do you mean by that? Does it not invoke the corresponding GestureDetector's onTap function? What happens when you do that?

Comment: u can use flatbutton with rich text to achieve this. if you want full code then please let me know.

Comment: @ParthPitroda If you could provide a code, it would be awesome.

Comment: @NoumanHanif Already tried that, doesn't work. That's what I want to achieve anyways, two separate actions for the buttons. That means two GestureDetectors.

Comment: This is a comment I'm making for the ones who disliked this post, if you could give me one single reason why the .... you disliked it, please let me know, so I can improve myself (even if there isn't a reason), thanks!

Comment: @ArdaÇebi Please add code part of `rowCell` function

Comment: @ArdaÇebi I specifically asked what you mean it doesn't work? If you explain what happens then it will be easier for everybody to understand your problem. Simply saying 'doesn't work' is too vague. whether callbacks don't get called, app crashes, or callbacks for both gesture detectors get called when interacting with one. There is a lot that can count as 'doesn't work'.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `rowCell` with `GestureDetector`then you will get separate onTap function with the same design.

Otherwise, you can use `GestureDetector` inside the `rowCell()`. And pass a function to the `rowCell()` to attach to the `GestureDetector`.

```
Widget rowSell(<your parameters>, Function onTapFunction) {
  return GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTapFunction,
        child: <Your child>
      ),
}
```

And pass the function like:

```
new Row(
       children: <Widget>[
         rowCell(10250, 'MEETUPS', (){ <on Tap code> }),
         rowCell(1520, 'FRIENDS', (){ <on Tap code> }),
       ],
 ),
```

Comment: Can you explain what to do more clearly? Like what to add to the parameters section, and "exactly" how to implement those pieces of code in my project. Especially the first one.

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqePcMyeoIY 
and after check the answer , If you found it's helpful, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GestureDetector probably isn't working because you're wrapping it around the text and in that scenario, it's rare that it will work because you the onTap space is relative to space the text covers on the screen.

Try giving some padding inside the rowCell and then wrap it in a gesture detector, it will probably break your layout but at least you will know the problem and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

If rowCell is return widget then wrap rowCell with GestureDetector and get click of that...

```
...

new Divider(
            height: _height / 20,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: rowCell(10250, 'MEETUPS')),
                GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: rowCell(1520, 'FRIENDS')),
            ],
          ),
          new Divider(height: _height / 20, color: Colors.grey),

...
```

Comment: I've already tried this, the error I'm getting is: "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget: Expanded widgets must be placed directly inside flex widgets."

Answer (score 0):

From the comment from above you mention, I assume your `rowCell` function returns an `Expanded` widget.

So in `rowCell` function, inside `Expanded` widget add `Inkwell` widget. Also add one more argument which tells the page that you want to navigate to (`onTap`).

```
Widget rowCell(int count, String title, Widget navTo){
  return Expanded(
    child: Inkwell(
      onTap: () => _navToPage(navTo)
      child: .... //Your child widget 
    ),
  );
}
```

```
void _navToPage(Widget navTo){
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => navTo,
    ),
  );
}
```

```
    new Divider(height: _height / 20, color: Colors.grey),
    new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: rowCell(10250, 'MEETUPS', MeetupsPage())),
            GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: rowCell(1520, 'FRIENDS', FriendsListPage())),
        ],
    ),
    new Divider(height: _height / 20, color: Colors.grey),
```